# Bathymetric-topographic DEM color relief?

Tags: qgis, dem, color-ramp

I am using QGIS 2.12 on a Macbook Pro running OS X 10.10.5.

I have an interesting DEM for the California coast (which I downloaded from [Santa Barbara, CA 1/3 arc-second MHW DEM](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/dem/squareCellGrid/download/603).

I've been playing with color ramps for this. How can I get the colors to change smoothly yet still break from blues to greens exactly at sea level (elevation zero)?

The only way I have succeeded in getting a precise break at the shoreline (sea level) is to have discrete color changes. But that does not look good at all in areas away from the shoreline.

Answer (score 2):

There is several ways you can accomplish this. I would start playing with the min / max value and number of classes in equal mode to see if you can get a match for you need. You can also do it manually editing the value and color directly in the color band scale. The plus and minus button can add classes manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I had the same problem. After a while of "playing around" as suggested in the other answer, it dawned on me that having both a smooth gradient and a hard cut at 0 is difficult to achieve this way. There is an easy solution, however, if you don't mind cheating a bit.

The easiest way to accomplish this is probably to duplicate your DEM layer: Have one layer for everything below sea level and another one for everything above. That way you can have both smooth gradients for below and above sea level *and* a sharp cut between them easily:

The lower bathymetry layer gets a gradient of blues from e.g. -50m to 0m.

[image]

The upper topography layer gets a gradient of greens from e.g. 0 to whatever you highest mountain has. The trick then is to make everything below 0 transparent for this layer, so that the blues of the bathymetry layer below can shine through (this is the only "manual" edit you have to do with this).

[image]

I'll probably look for some nicer looking gradients, but in principle this works for me.