# Effectively applying cpt-city colour ramps to elevation in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, elevation, topography

There are lots of nice topography and bathymetry colour ramps provided by cpt-city in QGIS. However, I cannot find a straightforward way of specifying the transition from blue (below sea level) to greens/browns (above sea level) at (or in the region) of 0. Instead, I get something like this:[image]
I could manually edit the values but this seems cumbersome especially over a large range.  Currently, the best option appears to be the one proposed here (split the data into 2, 1 above sea level, one below sea level):
[Bathymetric-topographic DEM color relief?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169613/bathymetric-topographic-dem-color-relief?rq=1)

Is there a way to set a certain value, e.g. 0, and then force the recalculation of the others? At the moment if I change the blue/green value to 0, it just reorders the colours. Am I missing something obvious in how these colour ramps should be applied?

Comment: You can force the classification to be Min/Max defined by user. You can define Min and Max with opposite numbers, like -100 and 100, -500 and 500, etc. wide enough for your data to be in that range.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful suggestion - and it works. I had to play with the min/max values as the ramp I was using wasn't symmetrical (more colours in the green/brown end).

Comment: I'm glad it was useful to you. If you wanted to write and accept your own answer, about the solution for your particular case, that would be useful also for future searches.